# What is the expected number of blue beads selected as a result of this experiment?

Tags: probability

Imagine two boxes, a yellow one and a green one. The yellow box contains 13 blue beads and 8 red ones. The green box contains 15 blue beads and 4 red ones. We toss a fair coin. If it lands on heads, we select a random bead from the yellow box, and otherwise we select a random bead from the green box. 
a)Suppose that as a result of this experiment, a blue bead was selected. What is the probability that the coin landed on heads? 
b)In the setup of the previous question, suppose that instead of selecting just one bead, you randomly select three. What is the expected number of blue beads selected as a result of this experiment?

I found the answer to part a to be 247/562. However, I'm not sure about part b.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set it up as a tree: coin toss outcome, then the getting a bead from the relevant box. As the coin toss is independent from the bead selection, you can multiply probabilities, add up probabilities along branches that lead to the outcomes that interest you.

In general, try to come up (or search your textbooks or the web) with structured ways to solve problems. That way it is more likely you get the right answers, fast. The above tree structure is actually one of the standard tricks of the trade.

Answer (score 0):

@Margaret

vonbrand is right.Drawing the tree when possible is a great help.

I am reading your part b as meaning half the time you draw 3 balls without replacement from the yellow box and the other half, 3 balls without replacement from the green.

I am getting using the formula for expectation and the hypergeometric distribution:

$E(blue)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{13 \binom{21-13}{3-1}}{\binom{21}{3}}(1)+\frac{(13-1) 13 \binom{21-13}{3-2}}{2 \binom{21}{3}}(2)+\frac{(13-2) (13-1) 13 \binom{21-13}{3-3} }{6 \binom{21}{3}}(3)+\frac{15 \binom{19-15}{3-1}}{\binom{19}{3}}(1)+\frac{(15-1) 15 \binom{19-15}{3-2}}{2 \binom{19}{3}}(2)+\frac{(15-2) (15-1) 15 \binom{19-15}{3-3}}{6 \binom{19}{3}}(3)\right)=\frac{281}{133}$